# Ansible handlers not triggering in roles

Tags: ansible

I have below role where in I defined handler notify under tasks/main.yml and handler in handlers/main.yml
when I did -vvvv it shows triggered Handler but the handler task output is not executing.
Could someone comment whether anything is missing.

```
---
# tasks file for /etc/ansible/roles/ios
      - name: Test
        changed_when: true
        ios_command:
           commands: "{{ Model }}"
        notify: 
            - trigger command

---
# handlers file for /etc/ansible/roles/ios
     - name: "trigger command"
       debug:
          msg: Success

# Tree structure:
├── handlers
│   └── main.yml
├── tasks
│   └── main.yml
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update the question. It will be closed If you don't provide the details (minimal, but complete and verifiable).

Comment: Are you sure the handler task is not executing? Show us the output

Comment: Output says handler got triggered but I don't see the debug message after the first task..instead it just continued with the next task in my play....